# Detect if key or mouse paste was performed

Tags: jquery

Working with jquery 1.3.2. I use this code

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
```

to detect id there was an key input in my form. However, it wont detect if I paste something inside form. How can be this achieved? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `input` event that you can use for all manner of key presses, pasting, clearing, etc:

```
$('#myInput').bind('input', function() {
     // Your handler
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the change event:

```
$('#myInput').change(function() {
   //your code
});
```

In modern browsers, there's also a `paste` event. If you don't mind getting multiple events, you could do something like this:

```
$('#myInput').bind('keyup change paste', function() {
   //your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript by default have a specific event that can be triggered by the HTML itself:

```
<input ... onpaste="myFunction()"/>
```

You can then easily define `myFunction` as you like.

Alternatively using jQuery you can bind the following event:

```
    $("#myInput").bind('paste', function(e) {
        ...
    });
```